# Remove vertical lines in matplotlib seaborn pointplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a problem with my Pointplot styling in seaborn and tried eveything to fix it but nothing seems to work. You can see my original dataframe below

```
    year  künstliche intelligenz   ki  artificial intelligence  ai
0   2000                      28   16                        4   0
1   2001                       0    0                        0   0
2   2002                       0    0                        0   0
3   2003                       4    0                        0   0
4   2004                       0    0                        0   0
5   2005                       0    0                        0   0
6   2006                       8    0                        0   0
7   2007                      12    0                        0   0
8   2008                       0    0                        0   0
9   2009                       0    0                        0   0
10  2010                       4    0                        0   0
11  2011                       4    0                        0   0
12  2012                       4    0                        0   0
13  2013                       4    0                        0   0
14  2014                      12    0                        0   0
15  2015                      48   24                        8  48
16  2016                      88   92                        8   4
17  2017                      96   48                        0   0
18  2018                     124  124                        4   0
19  2019                      84  292                        0   0
20  2020                      28    8                        0   0
```

on this DF I run these commands and get the resulting graph below

```
data = data.melt('year', var_name='cols', value_name='vals')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6.3792, 6.3792))
sns.pointplot(x="year", y="vals", hue='cols', data=data, colors=sns.color_palette('colorblind'), scale=0.4,
                 ci=None)
ax.set(yscale='log')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax.set_yticks([1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512])
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30)
plt.show()
```

[image]

my problem are the vertical lines to the X-Axis at the beginning and end of a point series.
Is there a way to remove these vertical lines?

Comment: for anyone wondering the problem were the 0s in the DF. Apparently you're supposed to fill them with np.nan

Answer (score 1):

Those vertical lines represent **confidence levels**, as stated in docs for [sns.pointplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html).
If you don't want to show them in the chart, take a look at [sns.lineplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/wide_data_lineplot.html).

Comment: thanks for the comment, I used lineplot first. The Problem ist lineplot wont show single points with no connections (the blue point at 2003 would not show up for example)